# please help me to solve the integral of equation F as depicted .$F(\mu)=1-\int_{x-(-2\alpha^2\ln\mu)^{1/2}}^{x+(-2\alpha^2\ln\mu)^{1/2}}p(c)dc$

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function

I am a civil engineer and for one part of my thesis I studied an article. In that article a parametric equation p(c) is defined as below:
$$p(c)=
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}\sigma}\exp\left(-\frac{(c-u)^{2}}{2\sigma^2}\right)$$   eq.1

and $F(\mu)$ is probability distribution function (CDF)and it is defined as:

$$F(\mu)=1-\int_{x-(-2\alpha^2\ln\mu)^{1/2}}^{x+(-2\alpha^2\ln\mu)^{1/2}}p(c)dc$$   eq.2

in that article the probability density function (PDF) is defined as:

$$p(\mu)=(F(\mu))'=-(\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}\sigma}\exp(-\frac{(x+(-2\alpha^2\ln\mu)^{1/2}-u)^2}{2\sigma^2})\times(x+(-2\alpha^2\ln\mu)^{1/2})'-\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{1/2}\sigma}\exp(-\frac{(x-(-2\alpha^2\ln\mu)^{1/2}-u)^2}{2\sigma^2})\times(x-(-2\alpha^2\ln\mu)^{1/2})')=\frac{1}{2(2\pi)^{1/2}\mu\sigma}(\frac{-2\alpha^2}{\ln\mu})^{1/2}\times(\exp(-\frac{(x+(-2\alpha^2\ln\mu)^{1/2}-u)^2}{2\sigma^2})+\exp(-\frac{(x-(-2\alpha^2\ln\mu)^{1/2}-u)^2}{2\sigma^2}))$$         eq.3

In my thesis, I need to write these equations in the Simulink function (Matlab). So, I need to know what is the simplified form of equation $F(\mu)$ when we put $p(c)$ in eq.2.

I think it is very complicated and I would be appreciated if anybody can solve the parametric equation $F(\mu)$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed-form for the integral. The function $p$ is the density function of the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

You can write the result in terms of [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) of standard normal distribution though.

---

In MATLAB, you can use the [Normal cumulative distribution function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normcdf.html) `normcdf` to represent $F$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \frac{e^{-\frac{(c-u)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{\sqrt{\pi } \sigma } \, dc=\frac{\text{erf}\left(\frac{c-u}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+C$$

$$F(\mu)=1-\int_{x-\sqrt{-2 \alpha ^2 \log (\mu )}}^{x+\sqrt{-2 \alpha ^2 \log (\mu )}} \left(\frac{e^{-\frac{(c-u)^2}{2 \sigma ^2}}}{\sqrt{\pi } \sigma }\right) \, dc=$$
$$=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left[\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{-\alpha ^2 \log (\mu )}+\frac{u}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}}{\sigma }\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{-\alpha ^2 \log (\mu )}-u+x}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)\right]$$